# Why is $(Ad\, x)^*(u)(X) = u(Ad(x^{-1})X)$ for $u\in (T_eG)^*$ and $X\in T_eG$?

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

This question concerns Springer's "Linear Algebraic Groups" 2nd Edition page 69.

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group. For $x\in G$ we have an automorphism $Int(x):G \to G$, $y \mapsto xyx^{-1}$ fixing $e$ and therefore inducing linear automorphisms $$Ad \,x:T_eG \to T_eG,$$  $$(Ad\, x)^*:(T_eG)^* \to (T_eG)^*$$ of the tangent and cotangent space. Thus for $u\in (T_eG)^*$ we have $$(Ad \,x)^*(u)(X) = u(Ad(x^{-1})X) \quad (x\in G,\, X\in T_eG).$$

---

Why is the right side of the equation not $u(Ad(x)X)$?

Dont we have the identity $\langle f^*(\varphi),v\rangle = \langle \varphi, f(v)\rangle $ for $\langle\_\, ,\,\_\rangle $ the natural pairing of dual spaces, $v\in V$, $ \varphi \in V^*$, $f:V\to V$ and therefore

$$\begin{align}
(Ad \,x)^*(u)(X)&=\langle (Ad\, x)^*(u),X\rangle \\
&= \langle u, (Ad\, x)(X)\rangle \\
&=u((Ad\, x)(X))?
\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm studying the same book! Would you like a study buddy? If so, follow the website link on my profile here to my university profile. There's a public email address for me there.

Comment: I'm only on page 46 though . . .

Comment: Better yet, here: s.isherwood.22@abdn.ac.uk.